# Mouse Hooking, overriding mouse methods

Tags: c#, service, hook, mouse

I want to override every method related to bluetooth mouse(only)  actions, such as: click or movement. 
I am working on a windows service in C#, and I want to cancel, any of the BLE mouse actions globally.
I found how to do it, in Winforms, but not globally in Windows Service.

Comment: Does the Windows Service run in the interactive context? This may not be possible in C#, what you are asking to do is low-level hooks. Doing it for a single form is easy because you can intercept `WndProc`, but doing it at the OS level is another thing entirely.

Comment: So maybe you know how can I do it in c++? I can create a dll to use it in the C# service

Comment: Even that isn't trivial, Windows prevents those kinds of things to prevent malicious software like key loggers and mouse-loggers. It isn't easy (or maybe impossible) for a reason.

Comment: If I want to ignore the data that I get only from the Bluetooth mouse, do you think it is possible?

Comment: If it is installed as a system device, then if it is, it will be extremely difficult. It may be easier to intercept the Bluetooth connection before Windows installs it as a mouse and emulate a new mouse, but this is outside my expertise.

Comment: I succeeded by using Blockinput function, of Win32. It blocks they keyboard and mouse. I want it to block mouse only, maybe you are familiar with this function?